# Everything is a file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cd-command

In Linux, every single entity is considered as FILE. If I do `vim <cd-Name>` then, `vim` will open the directory content into it's editor, because, it do not differentiate between file and directories.

But today while working, I encountered a thing, which I am curious to know about.

I planned to open a file from nested directory

```
vim a/b/c/d/file
```

But instead of `vim`, I typed

```
 cd a/b/c/d/
```

and hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice, but command was showing only the available directory of the "d" directory rather files.

Don't the `cd` command honour "*everything is a file*"? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: vim differentiates between files and directories (it even says "`"." is a directory`" when you open one); it just thinks you might find it useful to use it as a tree browser. It's not related to the "everything is a file" mantra.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The "*Everything is a file*" phrase defines the architecture of the operating system. It means that everything in the system from processes, files, directories, sockets, pipes, ... is represented by a file descriptor abstracted over the [virtual filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) layer in the kernel. The virtual filesytem is an interface provided by the kernel. Hence the phrase was corrected to say "*Everything is a file descriptor*". Linus Torvalds himself corrected it again a bit more precisely: "*Everything is a stream of bytes*".

However, every "file" has also an owner and permissions you may know from regular files and directories. Therefore classic Unix tools like cat, ls, ps, ... can query all those "files" and it's not needed to invent other special mechanisms, than just the plain old tools, which all use the `read()` system call. For example in Microsofts OS-family there are multiple different `read()` system calls (I heard about 15) for any file types and every of them is a bit different. When everything is a file, then you don't need that.

**To your question**: Of course there are different file *types*. In linux there are [7 file types](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html). The directory is one of them. But, the utilities can distinguish them from each other. For example, the complete function of the `cd` command (when you press <kbd>TAB</kbd>) only lists directories, because the `stat()` system call (see `man 2 stat`) returns a struct with a field called `st_mode`. The POSIX standard defines what that field can contain:

```
       S_ISREG(m)  is it a regular file?
       S_ISDIR(m)  directory?
       S_ISCHR(m)  character device?
       S_ISBLK(m)  block device?
       S_ISFIFO(m) FIFO (named pipe)?
       S_ISLNK(m)  symbolic link? (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)
       S_ISSOCK(m) socket? (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)
```

The `cd` command completion function just displays "files" where the `S_ISDIR` flag is set.

Answer (score 7):

Your shell is smart enough to know that `cd` will not work with file parameters. So when you hit `tab` it only shows things in that directory that will work with `cd`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `cd` is a builtin of `bash`. `TAB` completion is a controlled by bash options, you can find various completion script in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` and `/etc/bash_completion.d`. `cd`'s completion method is defined in the former one. As `cd` only works on directory, it's natural to only list available directory.
2. Everything is file in linux.

Comment: Everything is a file unless it's a directory. I remember doing `od -x .` to find out what funny characters someone had put into a filename. Try this today. You can use `hexdump` if `od` is not on your system.

Comment: please refer to @chaos answer.