# History of the saying "Everything is a file"

Tags: linux, historical-unix

Upon my journey to master Unix/Linux, I came across this saying and some of its derivaties:

> Everything is a file.

or

> Everything in Unix is a file.

Reflecting upon my humble knowledge of Unix/Linux, I think this phrase concisely defines a very foundational idea of the Unix/Linux system.

As such, I would like to use this quote in my up-coming presentation on Linux introduction. For that purpose, I need to know the history behind this quote with reference.

Comment: Other operating systems have done the same (recalling it for IBM VM/SP CMS).  The origin of this is probably debatable.

Comment: I understand that it won't be easy to give a proper reference to the 'history' of this saying. However, since I would like to put this line as a quote in my presentation I need to know at least what the general community thinks the 'source' of this quote is (e.g. *generally accepted* first document or person that used this saying).

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that it encourages others to provide their opinion rather than facts.

Comment: _history … with reference_ seems to be asking for documented facts.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141016/ and  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225537/ .

Comment: I understand your concern. I by no means want to go against the guideline of the community regarding appropriate questions. I thought if one can give a proper reference to justify his/her answer, it would become a fact rather than an opinion. However, do you think it is possible to edit this question to make it align more with the Unix&Linux stack guideline? Please help me with it.

Comment: I don't know the origin of that exact quote, but any explanation of that quote probably references [the 1974 CACM article on UNIX](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cacm.html).

Answer (score 1):

A case-insensitive [Ngram search for *"Everything is a file,Everything in Unix is a file"*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Everything%20is%20a%20file%2CEverything%20in%20Unix%20is%20a%20file&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CEverything%20is%20a%20file%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Beverything%20is%20a%20file%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEverything%20is%20a%20file%3B%2Cc0) doesn't turn up much, but it does give a date to beat:

> In iPcress **everything is a file**, including
>   the indexed table of file headers (inode table). This is an extension of the UNIX philosophy that “all files are simply a stream of bytes".
>    - [FILE SYSTEM DESIGN USING LARGE MEMORIES](ftp://ftp.cs.princeton.edu/reports/1989/246.pdf), Carl Staelin, Hector Garcia-Molina;
>   CS-TR-246-90
>   February 1990
>   (Revised June 1990)

---

Comment: Google will find a 1988 date with no problem, but the origin would be before **1980**.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I agree, but maybe this'll inspire a earlier find.